# Angular create Selector Tag <app-component> using variable or loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

I need to make the Selector Tag of my app.component.html using a variable.

Suppose variable name is: `componentVar:string`

I need my app.component.html:

`<componentVar></componentVar>` or `<app-componentVar></app-componentVar>`

Comment: You want to create components dynamically ? Why do you want your component selector to be name after a variables value ?

Comment: I have a lot of components attached in app-component.html, in which I have to put condition to show hide them. So, if it could possible to create selector tags using variable then I'll create them using a loop and use conditions as will.

Comment: *ngIf is ok, but I need to name the selectors using dynamic values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically create your components within a ViewcontainerRef like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4asbmc

(Don't forget to add the components you want to dynamically inject in your dom in your app module's entryComponents)

Once you are able to insert the components you shoud be able to manage which components have to be inserted into your with conditions.

**Edit**

You can iterate on an array of component that could look like this:

```
let componentArray = [HeaderComponent, BannerComponent, FooterComponent];
```

and then iterate over this array calling the method that inserts your components in your viewcontainer reference.

```
  createComponent(component) {
    const factory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const componentRef = factory.create(yourViewContainerRef.parentInjector);
    yourViewContainerRef.insert(componentRef.hostView);
  }
```

Though it would be musch easier to just call your components from your app component html template, and have something like this in your template:

```
<app-header *ngIf="yourConditions..."></app-header>
<app-banner *ngIf="otherConditions..."></app-banner>
<!-- and so on.... -->
```

Comment: What you have explained will work but it's something different than my expectation. I cant use this as I have numbers of component to place.
I need a simple solution to create the selector tags from a array of selector-name like below.

Array of Selectors in app.component.ts:
[ "app-header", "app-banner", "app-content", "app-footer"]

app.component.html should like:
<app-header></app-header>
<app-banner></app-banner>
<app-content></app-content>
<app-footer></app-footer>

I need to render the above html using the above array.

Comment: I updated the stackblitz to show you how you can create the components you want. 
Basically you should create an Array of component like this:
`let componentArray = [HeaderComponent, BannerComponent, ...];
componentArray.forEach(component => createComponent(component));
`
The createComponent method is almost the same function that was used, except it now has a parameter, being the component type that should be created and inserted in your ng-template

Comment: Ok, let me try with this.